# building Equal Columns with space

Tags: html, css

im trying to build 3 equal columns without using table option in html 5

result should be this:

[image]

but so far the result is that one of them doesnt look like the other 2 even with
same css for all 3

[image]

any ideas? also im using bootstrap template for this website

```css
#refGan {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 193px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  height: 378px;
  margin-right: 90px;
}

#refGan img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#refGan h3 {
  font-family: Miso;
  text-align: center;
  color: #A53D3E;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#refGan hr {
  width: 30px;
  position: center;
  color: #f00;
  background-color: #A53D3E;
  height: 5px;
}

#refGan p {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

#refGan label {
  float: left;
  background: url(../pictures/button.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 129px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<section id="refGan">
  <h3>רומנטיקה</h3>
  <hr>
  <div><img src="pictures/romantic anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
  <p>
    זה בדיוק איך שזה נשמע. בסדרות מסוג זה העלילה היא סביב זוג שמתאהבים. הז'אנר הזה מאוד פופולארי בקרב נערות צעירות וביפנית יש לו שם מיוחד: "שוג'ו".
  </p>
  <label>
                        לסדרות מומלצות
                    </label>
</section>
<section id="refGan">
  <h3>
    אקשן
  </h3>
  <hr>
  <div><img src="pictures/action anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
  <p>
    ז'אנר קלאסי שמשלב בדרך כלל אומנויות לחימה וגיבור מרכזי אחד. הז'אנר הזה מאוד פופולארי בקרב נערים צעירים וביפנית יש לו שם מיוחד: "שונן".
  </p>
  <label>
                        לסדרות מומלצות
                    </label>
</section>
<section id="refGan" class="marcoCol">
  <h3>הרפתקאות</h3>
  <hr>
  <div><img src="pictures/adventure anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
  <p>
    הז'אנר המוכר מכולם! הוא אפילו חדר למדינות מעבר ליפן. כולל בתוכו סדרות כמו: הלב (מרקו) ונילס הולגרסון. מה שמאפיין אותו, כמובן, זה ההרפתקאות של הגיבור הראשי.
  </p>
  <label>
                        לסדרות מומלצות
                    </label>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your sectons in a div

```
       <div style="display: flex;">
```

should fix your problem. But i made more changes to it to make it responsive also. That way you dnt need to hard code widths and margin.

```css
#refGan {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    height: 378px;
}

    #refGan img {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    #refGan h3 {
        font-family: Miso;
        text-align: center;
        color: #A53D3E;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #refGan hr {
        width: 30px;
        position: center;
        color: #f00;
        background-color: #A53D3E;
        height: 5px;
    }
    #refGan p {
        font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: black;
    }

    #refGan label {
        float: left;
        background: url(../pictures/button.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 129px 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
           <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around;">
                <section id="refGan">
                    <h3>רומנטיקה</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div><img src="pictures/romantic anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
                    <p>
                        זה בדיוק איך שזה נשמע. בסדרות מסוג זה העלילה היא סביב זוג שמתאהבים. הז'אנר הזה מאוד פופולארי בקרב נערות צעירות וביפנית יש לו שם מיוחד: "שוג'ו".
                    </p>
                    <label>
                        לסדרות מומלצות
                    </label>

                </section>
                <section id="refGan">
                    <h3>
                        אקשן
                    </h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div><img src="pictures/action anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
                    <p>
                        ז'אנר קלאסי שמשלב בדרך כלל אומנויות לחימה וגיבור מרכזי אחד. הז'אנר הזה מאוד פופולארי בקרב נערים צעירים וביפנית יש לו שם מיוחד: "שונן".
                    </p>
                    <label>
                        לסדרות מומלצות
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section id="refGan" class="marcoCol">
                    <h3>הרפתקאות</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div><img src="pictures/adventure anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
                    <p>
                        הז'אנר המוכר מכולם! הוא אפילו חדר למדינות מעבר ליפן. כולל בתוכו סדרות כמו: הלב (מרקו) ונילס הולגרסון. מה שמאפיין אותו, כמובן, זה ההרפתקאות של הגיבור הראשי.
                    </p>
                    <label>
                        לסדרות מומלצות
                    </label>
                </section>
            </div>
```

Comment: i didnt learn yet about this option with div - i dont know if its correct semantically for HTML5. so i cant use it :(
but this:

#refGan {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    height: 378px;
    margin-right: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

}

fixed the code!!!!!! now they are equal!!!!
thank you!!!!

Comment: it is according to html 5 standards  :) its relatively new but you must read about flex. it will help you a lot.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox  You can read about flex here

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap 
replace your html code in

```
<div class="container">
<section id="refGan" class="float-left col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
                <h3>רומנטיקה</h3>
                <hr>
                <div><img src="pictures/romantic anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
                <p>
                    זה בדיוק איך שזה נשמע. בסדרות מסוג זה העלילה היא סביב זוג שמתאהבים. הז'אנר הזה מאוד פופולארי בקרב נערות צעירות וביפנית יש לו שם מיוחד: "שוג'ו".
                </p>
                <label>
                    לסדרות מומלצות
                </label>
            </section>
            <section id="refGan" class="float-left col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
                <h3>
                    אקשן
                </h3>
                <hr>
                <div><img src="pictures/action anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
                <p>
                    ז'אנר קלאסי שמשלב בדרך כלל אומנויות לחימה וגיבור מרכזי אחד. הז'אנר הזה מאוד פופולארי בקרב נערים צעירים וביפנית יש לו שם מיוחד: "שונן".
                </p>
                <label>
                    לסדרות מומלצות
                </label>
            </section>
            <section id="refGan" class="marcoCol float-left col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
                <h3>הרפתקאות</h3>
                <hr>
                <div><img src="pictures/adventure anime.jpg" width="173" height="99" /></div>
                <p>
                    הז'אנר המוכר מכולם! הוא אפילו חדר למדינות מעבר ליפן. כולל בתוכו סדרות כמו: הלב (מרקו) ונילס הולגרסון. מה שמאפיין אותו, כמובן, זה ההרפתקאות של הגיבור הראשי.
                </p>
                <label>
                    לסדרות מומלצות
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
```

and delete this css code:

```
#refGan {
float: left;
width: 25%;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
height: 478px;
margin: 50px;
```

}